# how to get which filter is applied first in layered navigation

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, filtered-nav

I need the order on which the filter is applied.for example if we select red value in color attribute and then we select  L value in size attribute means I need that order ie)color and then Size not size and color .I want order on which filter is applied

Scenario:image :[image link](https://prnt.sc/ta6bca)
In this image i have first selected blue color next i have selected category jackets .I need the value of color because it is first selected but after selecting category, category  goes first

Comment: Hi @Jothi, As-far i know, Magento will always filter according to the sort order of the attribute.
Hope, this helps

Comment: Hi @kaushikkumarroy I have updated my question.category always goes first in layered navigation

Answer (score 0):

So if you're talking about ordering the layered/filtered nav on the category listing page (in the sidebar left or right), like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNXvp.jpg then you can set each number for the attribute under:

Attribute Name > Storefront Properties > Position (Position of attribute in layered navigation block.) like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvKte.jpg

Kind of a pain if you have more than 20 attributes but you'll need to start from 0, 1, 2, 3, etc for each one to order them the way you wish. So if you have: Brand, Price, Size, Color as your nav filters (attributes), you'll want to number them as shown, Brand - 0, Price - 1, Color - 2, Size - 3.

Now you'll have color before size. If you wish it to be the other way simply set position as Size - 2, Color - 3. This is how you order the filters/attributes.

Comment: hi @fadedout I have updated my question